# Is there a max number of icons I can store in an ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I currently have 4 actions in my action bar, and it cuts off the title of the screen. I know I can use `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to add a bottom bar, but I'm wondering if I can maybe make the Action icons smaller? I also know I could use the `ActionOverflow` option but I'm trying to avoid it if possible. If not, is there a max number I can hold on the bottom, and a max number for the top?

**EDIT**

Also, is there any sort of call like `setTitleTextSize()`? Maybe if I can make my title smaller it will work, but I can't find anything in the [`APIs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html).

Comment: This will vary from device to device, depending on screen size. AFAIK, nothing in the API will tell you this.

Comment: Thought so, thanks. Do you know of anyway to change the title's text size?

Comment: Nope, you can't change the title text size. You can create a custom ActionBar Layout and make the title and icons smaller, but I wouldn't suggest it, because it causes inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Google approved way to do this, but this minor hack should work.

```
try {
    final int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    TextView title = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(titleId);
    // check for null and manipulate the title as you see fit
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain action bar title reference");
}
```

However, a slightly more Google Approved way would be to set a custom layout to the ActionBar:

You can use a custom view for your action bar (it will display between your icon and your action items). I'm using a custom view and I have the native title disabled. All of my activities inherit from a single activity, which has this code in onCreate:

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

//if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
//I'm using a custom TextView with a custom font in my layout xml so all I need to do is set title
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());

//assign the view to the actionbar
this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

And your layout xml (R.layout.titleview in the code above) should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change `android:textSize="20dp"` to alter the size of the title.